# How to create column with request variable

Tags: php, laravel

I'm going to create new column in existing table with request data.
This is my code

```
$data = 'company';
Schema::table('users', function ($table, $data) {
    $table->string($data);
});
```

But function($table, $data) doesn't work.
Now users table exists.
If anyone has experienced in this field, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`Schema::create` only give you `$table` as the first argument, if you want to use the `$data` inside the `callback` function you have to use `use` keyword. Like this:

```php
$data = 'company';
Schema::table('users', function ($table) use ($data) {
    $table->string($data);
});
```

And if you are using PHP 7.4 or above, you can use the arrow function. Like this:

```php
Schema::table('users', fn ($table) => $table->string($data));
```